# Storing many variables in shared memory

Tags: c++, fork, shared-memory

I'm working with multithreading and shared memory and was just wondering what the best way to set up shared memory would be. So far, I've done this, all the keys are different:

```
if ((shmid1 = shmget(key1, 1024, IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
    error("ERROR on shmget1");

if ((shmid2 = shmget(key2, 1024, IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
    error("ERROR on shmget2");

if ((shmid3 = shmget(key3, 1024, IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
    error("ERROR on shmget3");
```

- With shmid1 I store an integer.
- With shmid2 I store an array of integers.
- With shmid3 I store an array of char*. (strings)

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared memory will attach to particular memory pointer in the kernel.
So the way you created shared memory id is correct.

Basic shared memory operations are,

shmget - create shared memory
shmat - create memory region in the kernel and assign to the variable
shmctl - shared memory control operations
shmdt - detach the memory from the kernel

you have created the shared memory id using shmget.

Now, You have to create and attach the memory to the variable. Whatever the value is,

```
void *shmat(int shmid, const void *shmaddr, int shmflg);
```

you can assign any variable to the pointer.

ex., void *var = `shmat(shmid, NULL, shmflg);`

now assuming you are going to store the array in shared memory variable. Then,

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3};
var = a;
```

Now the shared memory will contain the array variables. You can read it using the same shared memory key.

Thanks.